# Jqplot Bar chart have any adjustments in bars very large and small values?

Tags: jquery, bar-chart, jqplot

I am using Jqplot plugin to generate charts like bar. In My bar charts have two large values First bar and last bar. In between bars are too small. How to show the small bars adjust to large values .

[image]

Any way to match or adjust the other small value bars to high value bars .

Answer (score 5):

The graph was drawn like the above as it has the highest value 350500 and lowest value -5000 in it.So the y axes range is arranged automatically to include all the range of values.If your concern is the values 1600,993,2410,1854 etc.. are hardly unnoticeable then you can control the y-axis ticks by giving it a max value and a min value of your choice as shown below.

```
 axes: {
        xaxis: {
           //specify x-axis options here 
        },            
        yaxis: {
            min:-5000, //can give your choice of minvalue
            max:10000, //can give your choice of max value                
        }
    }
```

If the max value is given as 10000,you can see the graph adjust itself so that the values 1600,993,2410,1854 etc have become large and noticeable but you can see the bar corresponding to 350500 touches the top as it indicates the value is higher than 10000.You can use a highlighter then to know the exact value when they are moused over.Refer Jqplot documentation to know more details.